# LINQ-to-SQL: Stored Procedure that returns a single scalar value?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ-to-SQL for an application that queries a legacy database. I need to call a stored procedure, that selects a single integer value. Changing the stored procedure is not an option.

The designer creates a method with this signature:

```
private ISingleResult<sp_xal_seqnoResult> NextRowNumber([Parameter(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> increment, [Parameter(DbType="Char(3)")] string dataset)
```

I would like the return type to be int. How do I do this using LINQ-to-SQL ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would be trivial with a scalar function (UDF) rather than an SP. However, it should work easily enough - although if the SP is complex (i.e. FMT_ONLY can't inspect it 100%) then you might need to "help" it...

Here's some dbml that I generated from a simplfied SP that returns an integer; you can edit the dbml via "open with... xml editor):

```
<Function Name="dbo.foo" Method="foo">
    <Parameter Name="inc" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="dataset" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(20)" />
    <Return Type="System.Int32" />
</Function>
```

(note you obviously need to tweak the names and data-types).

And here is the generated C#:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.foo")]
public int foo([Parameter(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> inc, [Parameter(DbType="VarChar(20)")] string dataset)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), inc, dataset);
    return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

If your current SP uses SELECT (instead of RETURN), then the DBML will need to reflect this. You can fix this by hiding the implementation details, and providing a public wrapper in a partial class; for example:

```
<Function Name="dbo.foo" Method="FooPrivate" AccessModifier="Private">
    <Parameter Name="inc" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int" />
    <Parameter Name="dataset" Type="System.String" DbType="VarChar(20)" />
    <ElementType Name="fooResult" AccessModifier="Internal">
      <Column Name="value" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
    </ElementType>
</Function>
```

The above describes an SP that returns a single table with a single column; but I've made the SP "private" to the data-context, and the result-type "internal" to the assembly (hiding it):

```
[Function(Name="dbo.foo")]
private ISingleResult<fooResult> FooPrivate(
    [Parameter(DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> inc,
    [Parameter(DbType="VarChar(20)")] string dataset)
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), inc, dataset);
    return ((ISingleResult<fooResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

Now *in my own class file* I can add a new partial class (a new .cs file) in the correct namespace, that exposes the method more conveniently:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    partial class MyDataContext
    {
        public int Foo(int? inc, string dataSet)
        {
            return FooPrivate(inc, dataSet).Single().value;
        }
    }
}
```

(the namespace and context names need to be the same as the actual data-context). This adds a public method that hides the grungy details from the caller.

**Don't** edit the designer.cs file directly; your changes will be lost. Only edit either the dbml or partial classes.

Comment: @driss - if you get issues with SELECT, let me know

Comment: I have used the same technique in my project earlier on. It works great.. Untill you edit your DBML in the editor somehow. All your changes will be overwritten.
I used to keep a seperate xml file whenever I did manual alterations, but I hope there is a better way somehow.

Comment: @boris: which technique? Are you editing the .designer.cs? Don't do that... add methods to the partial class (I'll add an example)

Comment: The procedure uses SELECT. Your approach seemed to work at first, but I just discovered that the value field is always 0, no matter what the actual result is. Can this have to do with the column being selected not being named ? Can I specify in dbml, that value is the first column in the first row ?

Comment: @driis - 2 moments, I will investigate

Comment: @driis: it seems not; can you add a wrapped SP that calls the existing SP?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to make any schema changes in the database.

Comment: I am going to use SqlCommand for this. It just seems odd that it is not supported in LINQ-to-SQL, I think it is a common pattern for stored procedures (at least in the databases I am working with). Thanks for answering, you provided valuable insight in the options one have when working with dbml.

Comment: @driis - yes, it is a shame - but I believe that the L2S team are trying to enforce *some* kind of contract (per-name) on grid outputs. This is also used with the mappings etc. It is odd that index-based mapping isn't offered, though.

Answer (score 5):

RETURN @VALUE as the last statement of the proc.

then it will auto detect the type int, string, bool etc and generate the wrapper method accordingly.

Comment: +1 Returned value must come from a scalar variable so `RETURN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` and 1RETURN SELECT @Value = COUNT(*) FROM table1 will not work but `RETURN @Value` will. Also, MS SQL/LINQ to SQL does not seem to support tinyint/byte return types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio's .xsd file in a Linq to SQL classes project, make sure you:

1. Right click the stored procedure or function call in the Adapter.
2. Select Properties
3. **Change Execute Mode to Scalar**

That will make your adapter function return type to "Object".  You then need to cast it to int or string, or whatever type it should be.