# Linq to sql stored procedure return value

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure in an SQL Server 2005 database (meant simply to return the database size in MB).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbSize]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sizeMb int
DECLARE @DB_NAME varchar(100)

SELECT @DB_NAME = DB_NAME()

SELECT @sizeMb = (size*8)/1024 FROM sys.master_files
    WHERE DB_NAME(database_id) = @DB_NAME
    AND Name = @DB_NAME

RETURN @sizeMb  
END
```

When I run this in SQL Server Management Studio, it works correctly, returning the current DB Size in MB.

I want this to run inside an application, so I added it to a linq to sql datacontext, which generated the following code:

```
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.dbSize")]
    public int dbSize()
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
        return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

I call it like so:

```
int dbSize = db.dbSize();
```

However, it only returns zero, never anything else. No exceptions of any kind are thrown either.
 I experimented with selecting a result and using output parameters, but that didn't help either (the output parameter was zero as well). Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly, but as a general suggestion you might find it easier to use SMO to get [database properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database_properties) from a .NET application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into the same problem. As dumb as it sounds, you have to return a single row with single column containing your value from a *stored procedure*.  L2S doesn't do something akin to `ExecuteScalar(...)`.

If you use a *UDF*, you'll have better luck.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281210/is-it-possible-to-use-access-scalar-functions-with-linq-to-sql) speaks to the problem nicely.

Comment: Do you mean with an output parameter? I tried that, and got the same result...unless you mean something else?

Comment: Not with an output parameters, no.  A scalar-valued UDF should work fine.

Comment: Must I resort to a UDF? I have another SP in the application that I'm using in the exact same way and it works fine (it has four output parameters)

Comment: I just found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287106/linq-to-sql-stored-procedure-that-returns-a-single-scalar-value) that might clear up your problem.

Comment: I actually just ended up doing something similar (although I changed my SP to exec sp_spaceused). Thanks for your help :)